# Water drop sound effect in Lost

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, sound-effects, lost

What is the water drop-like clicking sound we hear in the camp or barracks all the time in *Lost*? Is there an explanation or meaning for this sound?

Comment: Do you mean the [Smoke Monster's clicky sounds](https://www.reddit.com/r/lost/comments/32lgfq/the_sounds_the_monster_makes/) or these [other Smoke Monster Sound Effects](https://www.reddit.com/r/lost/comments/cbyrs1/smoke_monster_sound_effects/)? or some other completely different sounds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What was the mechanic noise behind the Black Smoke Monster in Lost?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49266/what-was-the-mechanic-noise-behind-the-black-smoke-monster-in-lost)

Comment: Before people just 'assume' this is a duplicate, lets hear from Roots72.

Comment: not the smoke monster but just when they are within the perameters of the baracks or just indoors , nobody says anything about this ''clook click '' sound if i may write it like that , wish i could record it to play it here!

Comment: @Roots72: Could you tell some specific instances when this sound plays ? I assume that most of the time they are near ocean or waterbody, that's why the effect.

Comment: Do you have a clip were the sound can be heard?

Comment: you can ear it Thourout the seasons but went back to look for one moment where i could find one of them and if you look season 5 episodes 8 LaFeur at 36 min 30 sec to 37:26 you will ear it in the background

Comment: Even ear it in bed with Juliette & Goodwin in season 3 Ep. 16 One Of US at 26:25 to 29:35